# Migration of Salesforce Communities configurations between environments

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am looking at a technical POC using Salesforce Community Builder to create an externally visible application on top of Salesforce.  This would need us to be able to build in development environments and migrate into QA, UAT and Production orgs.

For the rest of Salesforce we extract the meta data into Bitbucket (git), and manage releases using Bamboo.  We would like to do the same with the communities site.

At the moment we can't see how we can do this, or anything similar - the meta data includes a ".site" and some xml config, but importing the site into Site.com doesn't appear to work.

Has anyone tried anything similar?

How do other people migrate communities sites from development, through QA into production?

Answer (score 0):

Migration .site file and some other xml config along with VF pages and apex controllers which might be working under the hood of community site.com is definitely working approach. I did it a few times in different projects and didn't found any issue with migration. Usually I use Apache Ant Migration tool and Eclipse IDE. I guess it's also possible with Change Sets.

Only one annoying feature of site.com is the fact that it's a binary file which contains all templates, static files, code, etc. and history changes itself. It can't be normally treated in version control. Actually you can't compare your changes between commits and that is really irritating fact.

So, I can't say something more concrete with details which you provided.

Comment: We have tried to export / import the .site file as you describe, but we have not managed to get it working.  Can you confirm that you have managed to migrate a *Community Builder* built site using the site.com tool?